# Event Calendar, rails 4, assocation with models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, events, calendar

Can somebody help me with a event calendar? I need a calendar showing medical appointments and treatments (and maybe some other stuff) for a person. I am trying to implement the `event_calendar` but I'm not sure how does it work.

How do you make the association between the models (treatment and appointment) and the calendar? Do I have to include has_event_calendar or something in all the models that I want to associate to my calendar?

Im following the https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar notes, but at the moment I only get an `undefined method 'first' for nil:NilClass`.

Thanks!!

:-)

Im getting an error in the `event_calendar` method in calendar_helper (in the line `calendar event_calendar_opts do |args|`).

```
module CalendarHelper
  def month_link(month_date)
    link_to(I18n.localize(month_date, :format => "%B"), {:month => month_date.month, :year => month_date.year})
  end

  # custom options for this calendar
  def event_calendar_opts
    { 
      :year => @year,
      :month => @month,
      :event_strips => @event_strips,
      :month_name_text => Time.zone.now.strftime("%B %Y"),
      :previous_month_text => nil,
      # :previous_month_text => "<< " + month_link(@shown_month.prev_month),
      # :next_month_text => month_link(@shown_month.next_month) + " >>" 
       :next_month_text => nil   
    }
  end

  def event_calendar
    # args is an argument hash containing :event, :day, and :options
    calendar event_calendar_opts do |args|
      event = args[:event]
      %(<a href="/events/#{event.id}" title="#{h(event.name)}">#{h(event.name)}</a>)
    end
  end
end
```

**My Terminal:**

```
Started GET "/users/67" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 17:26:09 +0200
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"67"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 67 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Person Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 67]]
  Rendered partials/_calendar.html.erb (209.6ms)
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (223.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 291ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass:
  event-calendar (2.3.3) lib/event_calendar/calendar_helper.rb:324:in `cal_row_heights'
  event-calendar (2.3.3) lib/event_calendar/calendar_helper.rb:88:in `calendar'
  app/helpers/calendar_helper.rb:22:in `event_calendar'
  app/views/partials/_calendar.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_partials__calendar_html_erb__1671607824421586091_2239325180'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:24:in `render'
  app/views/users/index.html.erb:343:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb__4590169231621808245_2170955760'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__1401478239041731936__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  meta_request (0.2.1) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:11:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.1.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
  meta_request (0.2.1) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
  meta_request (0.2.1) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
   () Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
   () Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
   () Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
   () Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
   () Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2649122141067380970__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
   () Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
   () Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
   () Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
   () Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
   () Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
   () Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
   () Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/danielcastillomarfull/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

**_calendar.html.erb**

```
raw(event_calendar)
```

Comment: At which line you get that error? Also post the relevant code.

Comment: Hi, Pavan. Its in the event_calendar method.

Comment: I can't see `first` anywhere in the code you posted.Are you sure the error is referring to that line?

Comment: I think that is the line. I post my terminal also.

Comment: Post your `_calendar.html.erb`.

Comment: My partial _calendar only contents <%= raw(event_calendar) %>

Comment: I decided to change my strategy. Now Im using fullcalendar

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to use fullcalendar instead of event_calendar. Im not sure if there is a problem with event_calendar and rails 4. This is my first calendar, anyway so maybe I was doing somehting wrong.